# How to answer incoming calls with Self-Managed ConnectionService

Tags: android, kotlin, android-phone-call, android-connectionservice

I've been building a standalone calling app in Android Studio with Kotlin following this `tutorial`: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged

I've implemented everything that's necessary and read the whole docs a few times over, yet still I can't make my code work. The problem I am having is answering incoming calls and making outgoing calls.

**Incoming calls:** According to the Logcat, every function is called in correct order. However, I always get the following information when there's an incoming call:

`I/TelecomFramework: CallHandler: reject TC@71_1: (...->CSW.hCCC)->CS.r->H.CS.r(cet/cast/cast)@E-E-E-Bn0`

`I/TelecomFramework: CallHandler: notifyCreateConnectionComplete TC@71_1: (...->CSW.hCCC)->CS.crCoC->H.CS.crCoC(cet/cast)@E-E-E-Bn0`

`CallHandler` is one of the classes that I've implemented and it extends `ConnectionService`. There's no function or command within that class that rejects the call (as shown in the info). When I try to answer my call with `call.answer()` or `connection.setActive()`, the app crashes without any error message. I've tried debugging and everything else that came to my mind but I can't find a solution.

***Outgoing calls:*** I really don't know why this doesn't work, it just seems like the connection isn't even built. Every function is called in correct order once again and I don't get any error messages.
I get the following informations though:

`I/TelecomFramework: CallHandler: notifyCreateConnectionComplete TC@173_1: (...->CSW.hCCC)->CS.crCoC->H.CS.crCoC(cast)@E-E-E-gX`

`I/TelecomFramework: CallHandler: onAudioStateChanged TC@173_1 [AudioState isMuted: false, route: EARPIECE, supportedRouteMask: EARPIECE, SPEAKER, activeBluetoothDevice: [null], supportedBluetoothDevices: []]: CS.cASC->H.CS.cASC@AAE`

Here's the `CallHandler` class:

```
class CallHandler : ConnectionService(){

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onCreateOutgoingConnection(
        connectionManagerPhoneAccount: PhoneAccountHandle?,
        request: ConnectionRequest?
    ): Connection {
        //return super.onCreateOutgoingConnection(connectionManagerPhoneAccount, request)

        val callConnection = CallConnection(applicationContext)

        callConnection.setInitializing()
        callConnection.setInitialized()
        callConnection.setDialing()
        callConnection.setActive()

        Log.i("CallHandler", "onCreateOutgoingConnection called")

        return callConnection
    }


    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onCreateIncomingConnection(
        connectionManagerPhoneAccount: PhoneAccountHandle?,
        request: ConnectionRequest?
    ): Connection {
      //  super.onCreateIncomingConnection(connectionManagerPhoneAccount, request)

        val callConnection = CallConnection(applicationContext)
        callConnection.setRinging()
        callConnection.setInitializing()
        Log.i("CallHandler", "onCreateIncomingConnection Called")

        return callConnection
    }
```

I've removed the `onCreateIncomingConnectionFailed`(and outgoing) functions as all they do is show a toast. `CallConnection()` is the class that extends `connection`and sets `connectionProperties = PROPERTY_SELF_MANAGED` in its init.

I'd really appreciate any help. I've been looking for the problem for multiple days now without finding the reason or a solution.